# How to properly handle zero bit width case?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When I write generic module, I often encounter 0-bit width case.

```
module test #(
    parameter WIDTH
) (
    input logic [31 : 0] x,
    output logic [31 : 0] y
);
    always_comb begin
        y = x[WIDTH - 1 : 0];
    end
endmodule
```

For example, the above module extracts lowest WIDTH bits from x.
When WIDTH is 0, output is don't care.
However, when the module is instantiated with WIDTH 0, I get the following error in Modelsim:

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-3373) test.sv(8): Range of part-select [-1:0] into 'x' [31:0] is reversed.
```

I tried the following code hoping for the bad part to be optimized out at compile time, but the error remains.

```
if (WIDTH == 0) y = 0;
else y = x[WIDTH - 1 : 0];
```

Is there any remedy to this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedural code needs to compile, even if the branch with the bad range is never taken.

```
module test #(
    parameter WIDTH
) (
    input logic [31 : 0] x,
    output logic [31 : 0] y
);
    always_comb
       if (WIDTH == 0) y = 'x;
       else y = x[WIDTH - 1 + (WIDTH==0): 0];
endmodule
```

---

You could also do

```
module test #(
    parameter WIDTH
) (
    input logic [31 : 0] x,
    output logic [31 : 0] y
);
if (WIDTH==0)
  assign y = 'x;
else
  assign  y = x[WIDTH - 1: 0];
endmodule
```

Comment: I prefer handling it inside always_comb (without assign), but the first method will not work when y is not don't care. (x[0] goes into y) Although I presented don't care example, my actual module needs to output 0 when WIDTH is 0. Is there another way in this situation?

Comment: Oh I was mistaken, x[0] does not go into y. Although it does not seem "clean", it works. Thanks.

Comment: You could replace `assign` with `always_comb` in my second example. As long as the `if` remains outside the procedural code, it becomes a `generate-if` construct.